# Error outputting a string to cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, string

I am using a vba macro to automate part of an excel spreadsheet.  The following line keeps giving me a runtime error 1004# application or object defined error

```
Sheets("Material").Last.Offset(0, 1).Value = "=SUMIF(MainTable[0],AG12,MainTable[Cost])"
```

Using watches I know that the left hand side of the equation is referencing the proper cell.  I'm assuming the error lies within the righthand string being wrote into the cell - I'm thinking possibly with my table references?  The rest of the formulas as strings all write fine and contain no table references.

Comment: Does setting any other value work fine? `Sheets("Material").Last.Offset(0, 1).Value = "A"` for example. The `Last` function looks suspicious to me.

Comment: Last is a range variable, that gets incremented with a loop and offset.  At the time I wrote this, I didn't understand arrays as I now do.

Comment: I see, so you have solved the problem then?

Comment: Yeah I just figured it out.  I'll post the answer - it is a simple mistake. I was overthinking.  Code is fine, the string formula itself was generating the error (referencing a non-existant table column).  If this question is not considered helpful, feel free to delete.

Comment: Alright, glad you worked it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed the error lay within the code because when I got the runtime error, there was no output to the given cell.  The problem actually occurs if a formulas were to be written to a cell and it would generate that pop up window that states "We've found a problem with this formula...." Not the same as #NAME?, #VALUE!, #N/A type errors.  In my case, my code set a range into a table, named MainTable and one of the column headers was Effective Cost.  The code set a formula as a string referencing MainTable[Cost], which should have been MainTable[Effective Cost].

The vba will generate a runtime error, the sub will come to a halt and the problem string will never be output to the cell. The following code will stop a sub. (the extra "(" will give the popup window formula error)

`Range("A1").Value = "=Sum((B2:B4)"`

The following code works uninterrupted although it does give a #NAME? error in the cell A1.

`Range("A1").Value = "=Sum(PotatoSalad)"`

I also did a quick test with an array of strings.  Storing formulas into strings within an array seems to circumvent the issue of code being interrupted as the formulas will not evaluate until refreshed.  This question goes into further detail regarding what happens when using an array to dump formulas into cells - Long story short  using a a variant array will cause formulas to evaluate and stop the sub. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238844/strange-behavior-when-assigning-a-vba-array-to-formulas-of-an-excel-range

The following code will work until cell A1 is forced to recalculate.

`Dim MyArray(0 to 0) as String
MyArray(0) = "=Sum((B2:B4)"
Range("A1").Value = MyArray()`

Passing the same array as a variant will generate a runtime error.